# How to change child values when its parent has been changed?

Tags: php, mysql

These are my database fields:

```
cat_id | cat_name | parent | cat_status | cat_image | parent_id
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | Mens     | --     | Active    | Some path  | 0

2      | Womens   | --     | Active    | Some path  | 0

3      | Shoes    | Mens   | Active    | Some path  | 1
```

Here is my database structure. Now if I Change/Update cat_name, from "Mens" to "Men" , it should reflect everywhere where "Mens" is present. Here in my case it is on entry no-3.
Here is my  HTML code for selecting the category:

```
<td> Category:</td><td><select name="parentcat" id="parentcat" onchange="getText(this)">

                <?php 


                    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
                    echo "<option value='-1'>--Select--</option>";
                    $result=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * from category"); 
                    $query10=mysql_query("select * from category where cat_id='$id'");

                    $query12=mysql_fetch_array($query10);
                    $parent_name =$query12['parent'];

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {    
                        if ($parent_name==$row['cat_name'])

                        {?>

                        <option selected value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></option>    

                        <?php }
                        else{?><option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php }

                          ?>

                    <?php } 
                    ?>

                    </select><input type="hidden" id="catnamehidden" name="hdnCatname" ><br/></td>
            </tr>
```

Here is my php code for that:

```
 if ($parentcat=='-1') 
                            {
                                echo "Selected and working";
                                $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE category SET cat_name='$catname',
                                           cat_status='$status'

                                          WHERE cat_id=$id");
                             }
```

What can I do to reflect changes?

Comment: you need to store category details in separate table and use its id in other places of category. so when category name changes, its id remains same

Comment: but  I can't I have that requirement mentioned so..

Comment: you are storing both parent_id and parent_name.. no need of that just only store parent_id

Comment: The I can fetch it's name from parent_id right? Then I don't need to store parent instead parent_id will work right?

Comment: Rijin is right. You can always get parent/cat name from parent_id which you are already storing. No need to store parent name separately.